# Sudden problem with build in TeXnicCenter, works fine in MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, texniccenter

I have a peculiar problem. I'm quite new to LaTeX but have used TeXnicCenter with MiKTeX for a while now without any major issues. However today, when I try to compile a `.tex` document to `.pdf`, I get the errors shown in the image below.

[image]

The exact same files have been working fine ten days ago but now this.

When I open the files directly in MiKTeX and "Typeset" them, they work fine.
What is the problem?

Comment: I guess when saying "open directly in MiKTeX" you mean the included TeXWorks editor?

Comment: Your path variable is being parsed as TeX directive. See `\MikTeX` part in the first error. I guess you forgot a brace `{` somewhere.

Comment: Percusse is correct, but the reason for that is still strange. I would suggest you delete your TeXnicCenter output profiles and regenerate them using the builtin assistant. It should call pdflatex then as follows `<path to pdflatex>\pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"`.

Comment: @Alexander Look at where the CV file is stored. I'm more inclined to believe that this is a user error. I also believe that this is after an `\input` statement.

Comment: @Alexander I have rebuilt it and the call is as you described, same errors though.
The real strange thing is the fact the the .tex files have worked fine before. It is when I open them today they have started returning these errors.

Comment: @marczellm Yes, that's what I mean =)

Comment: Problem solved finally. The files compile sucessfully when running TeXnicCenter as administrator. Don't remember having to do that before, but now it is all working fine again.
Sorry for troubling you all with was eventually turned out to be a windows problem rather than Latex/TexnicCenter

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by running TeXnicCenter as Administrator (Windows 7).

Not sure why it was needed this time though when I have not needed it before. Now after compiling once as administrator it works fine running TeXnicCenter as a "normal" user.